# A question based on property of a function satisfying $f(1/n) =0$ for every $n \in\mathbb{N} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying quiz questions of senior year and was unable to solve this particular question.

It's image:[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't think which result in analysis I can use. I am totally confused and would really appreciate if someone tells what should be done in such kind of problems.

Kindly help.

Answers :

> A, B, C

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851410/show-that-fn0-0-for-n-0-1-2-dots) for the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that $D$ is not true since there are infinitely many roots, which a non-zero polynomial can't have.

$A$ is true by continuity, as $\frac1n$ approachs $0$.

By the Mean Value Theorem, for each interval $\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$, there is a point in the interval with derivative $0$. As these points approach $0$, by continuity, $B$ is true.

The same argument using MVT twice shows that $C$ is true.

Comment: You don't need MVT....

Comment: @AnginaSeng: I think we need MVT for $f''(0)=0$. The first derivative $f' (0)=0$ can be handled by definition.